# Why is React asking for repeated props in static propTypes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

After running the test of my code, React says that there some props missing. So at the end I have this

```
  static propTypes = {
    'payoutInfo'                    : React.PropTypes.object,
    'payoutInfo.sideBetPayouts'     : React.PropTypes.arr,
    'payoutInfo.sideBetPayouts.map' : React.PropTypes.func,
  }
```

let me show you where the code comes from

here is the action. (I am using Flux)

```
class PayoutLimitActions {

  constructor () {
    this.generateActions('payoutsInfo');
  }

  payoutsInfo (payoutArray) {
    this.actions.payoutsInfo(payoutArray);
    this.dispatch();
  }
}

export default PayoutLimitActions;
```

here is the store

```
import PayoutLimitActions from 'actions/PayoutLimitActions';

@createStore(flux)
class PayoutLimitStore {

  constructor () {
    this.state = {
      payoutProp : localStorage.getItem('payoutArray') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('payoutArray')) : [],
    };
  }

  @bind(PayoutLimitActions.payoutsInfo)
  payoutsInfo (payoutArray) {
    this.setState({
      payoutProp : payoutArray,
    });
    localStorage.setItem('payoutArray', JSON.stringify(payoutArray));
  }
}

export default PayoutLimitStore;
```

here I have an `AuthStore` where I am using the `PayoutLimitActions`

```
axios.post(`${API_ENDPOINT}`, credentials)
  .then( (response) => {
    PayoutLimitActions.payoutsInfo(response.data.lobbyData);
    this.actions.authSuccess({...response.data, ...credentials});
  })
```

here the component

```
  <TableLimitsTooltip {...{
    payoutProp : this.props.payoutProp,
  }} />
```

so, why that would be happening ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be more useful to see the component code, not its use, to better understand what props you are actually using inside and how they are called.

Anyway, there is a mistake in the way you define types for an object. You must use the [`shape` type](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#prop-validation).

```
static propTypes = {
  payoutInfo: React.PropTypes.shape({
    sideBetPayouts: React.PropTypes.array
  })
}
```

Also, be aware that

- The `PropType` for an `Array` is `PropTypes.array`
- There is no need to define the PropTypes for the `Array.prototype.map`  method